Why is "FOX 5 NY’s Duarte Geraldino introduces us to the artists" not "introduces the artists to us"?
From Meet 'Rappin Max Robot'

With the first ever Olympic break dancing competitions happening in
Paris, a special tribute will be on display back here in New York
City. It comes in the form of a giant robot sculpture named "Rappin
Max Robot". FOX 5 NY’s Duarte Geraldino introduces us to the artists
and explains the meaning behind their design.

introduce A to B : He introduced me to a Greek girl at the party.
"Me" is A and "a Greek girl at the party" is B. But here the audience seems to be the A.

The sense you quote is more of a mutual acquaintance one. Although your analysis is logical, the writer is drawing on a slightly different sense. Compare the unambiguously acceptable "I want to introduce you to this artist's work." As Peter wrote, this would mean that you are now aware of the work -- the work can't possibly become aware of you. That's what's happening here.

Compare: "An Introduction to English Grammar".

@TimR But, here what comes after "to" is "artist", which is somebody not something.

I can see why you might find that distinction important, but in a TV context it is irrelevant since the artists are not there in person with "us", that is, the audience. This is a TV show that presents the artists as something the audience can learn about, analogous to a book presenting a subject to the reader.

The quotation is the opening paragraph in the article, and its use of introduce is correct.
Introduce has a range of meanings. Probably the most relevant meaning here is cause to become acquainted. And so when we read this:

Duarte Geraldino introduces us to the artists and explains the meaning behind their design.

...we understand that when we have finished reading the article we will be better acquainted with the artists and their work. We will know more about them than before we started reading, and in that sense we have been introduced to them.
(As confirmation, it doesn't work the other way. After reading the article, we know more about the artists, but they don't know anything about us. They certainly haven't been introduced to us.)
